# Ajax not returning php foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on here:

I have the following jquery/ajax code

```
$(document).on('click', '.get_friend', function() {
    var messenger = $(this).text();
    var user = '<? echo $username; ?>';
    $.ajax({
        url: '/includes/messenger.php',
        data: {messenger:  messenger, user: user},
        type: 'GET',
        success:function(data){
            $('#messages').html(data);
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Then my php file

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/config.php'); 

$user = $_GET['user'];
$messenger = $_GET['messenger'];
if (isset($_GET['messenger'])) { 
    $count1="0";
    $stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT message, sender, receiver, id, time FROM messenger WHERE (receiver = :receiver AND sender= :sender) 
                          OR (receiver = :sender AND sender=:receiver) ORDER BY time DESC");
    $stmt1->bindParam(':receiver', $user);   
    $stmt1->bindParam(':sender', $messenger);
    $stmt1->execute();
    $friend_msg = $stmt1->fetchAll();
    foreach ($friend_msg AS $friend_msg1) { 
        echo '1'; 
        $test = (++$count1 % 2) ? "itemOut" : "itemIn";

        $mesg .= '
            <div class="'.$test.'">
                <a href="#" class="image"><img src="img/users/olga.jpg" class="img-polaroid"/></a>
                <div class="text">
                    <div class="info clearfix">
                        <span class="name">'.$friend_msg1['sender'].'</span>
                        <span class="date">'.$friend_msg1['time'].'</span>
                    </div>  
                    '.$friend_msg1['message'].'
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
}
echo $count1;
echo $mesg;
echo $friend_msg;
echo $user;
echo $messenger;
```

the returns are as follows:

```
$count1 returns 0;
$mesg returns nothing
$friend_msg returns 'array'
$user returns the variable user as sent from ajax
$messenger returns the variable messenger as sent from ajax
```

If I visit the page directly using ?user=name&messenger=name2 the $mesg returns perfectly. The problem is fairly specific, ajax is not getting the results of the foreach returned at all.

Comment: @charlietfl I added error handling to the ajax code above, but being as its actually returning data, not sure how there would be an error. Its returning everything except $mesg.

Comment: if you use .= , the variable must be defined before, like `$mesg = ""; $mesg .= "text";`

Comment: @Eugen It will automatically use a null string by default if you don't initialize the variable. If you have warnings enabled it will print a message, but it will still work.

Comment: to prevent errors, use `isset()`, like `$user = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : false;
$messenger =  isset($_GET['messenger']) ? $_GET['messenger'] : false; if($user && $messenger) { // your code }`

Comment: @Barmar i don't know about his server settings and to prevent errors beter define empty var before get errors :-)

Comment: @Eugen There are no server settings that will cause an error for uninitialized variables. It's at worst a warning.

Comment: If you're getting `$count1 = 0` then the query isn't returning any rows.

Comment: @Barmar The weird thing is, I can use the exact same $user and $messenger variables directly and it returns perfectly. Example: messenger.php?messenger=user1&user=user2 will return perfectly. Sending those same usernames via ajax, returns the correct echo's on the users, but nothing from the database.

Comment: look in your console log for posted vars, maybe wrong.

Comment: Try `$(this).text().trim()`, there may be extra spaces around the name.

Comment: and once again you have solved my problems :) thank you so much Barmar.